# Concat two (or more) Observables and put in an array in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I've two oberservables in my typescript:

`ob_oj` and `ob_oj2`.

I concat the two observables like this:

```
Observable.concat(ob_oj,ob_oj2).subscribe(res=>{this.detailSatz=res;})
```

`detailSatz` is an Array from type any - I want to access to both results of `ob_oj` and `ob_oj2` via `detailSatz` in my HTML. But the results in the Array `detailSatz` were overrided, so I only get the results of `ob_oj2`.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a solution for a multiple number of observables? (An Array of observables)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use forkJoin and is best used when you have a group of observables and only care about the final emitted value of each. Try something like

```
var result = forkJoin([ob_oj, ob_oj2]).subscribe(
   result => console.log(result)
// result[0] is ob_oj
// result[1] is ob_oj2
)
```

Refer documentation: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Comment: Ok - can I also use forkJoin if I have a multiple number of observables?

Comment: Yes, you can use n number of observables and subscribe them to get the result in the form of array